# What to do when my app receives memory warning?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory, memory-management

What should I do when my app recieves a memory warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It all depends on your app, usually you don't have to do anything special except following Apple's recommended practices.

ViewControllers which are not visible at the moment will get `didReceiveMemoryWarning` message. By default (calling `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]`) controller's view is unloaded (released, freed). As the view is unloading, view controller receives `viewDidUnload` where you should release all your IBOutlets (or otherwise retained UI elements). Only then the view can completely be deallocated and memory freed.

In the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` you should also free as much data as you can - if you store some part of data model in ViewController, release it, and reconstruct in `viewDidLoad` that would be called when your view is loaded again (when user navigates back to this controller). You can inform your model classes to free memory too.

Comment: Thanks!... the last paragraph was the clue I'll been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your app.

If your app downloads and caches lots of contents from Internet for example, you should purge as much as possible when receiving a warning.

If your app is an OpenGL game, you might have a texture/sound/data manager which references some unused data, which you then want to free. Cocos2D manages this kind of things.

If your app isn't memory intensive, you have a memory leak somewhere, and you should 1) read the Memory Management Programming Guide by Apple 2) use Instruments/Leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, you should release any cached or non-essential items to prevent running out of memory completely.

Answer (score -1):

If you log or write to any other file, there might be an issue with "disk" space.

Also you should check for memory leaks.