# What should I do when I receive a memory warning?

Tags: iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do when my app receives memory warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023669/what-to-do-when-my-app-receives-memory-warning)

I developed an iPad App where I must display a lot of media (photos, videos, pdfs). My app uses the TabBar Application model. I found all of my memory leaks and now I am leaks-free but my App still crashes. I don't put any images in the cache with `imageWithContentsOfFile`, I release everything, the `movieplayer`, `UIImage`, `UIWebView`.  However, I still receive memory warnings. So what can I do with these warnings ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023669/what-to-do-when-my-app-receives-memory-warning ?

Comment: PANIC! Sorry. Couldn't resist. Yeah, it's a duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your images in memory in such a way that you can go back and purge them when the device asks for memory. And then you need a way of knowing what you've purged so you can reload it when you need it again.